# Update node with services doesn't work for text_list widget

Tags: 7, entities, services

I'm setting up a REST server with Drupal 7 and Services 3.x.
Everything work fine (authentication, node creation, etc..), except that I can't update a text_list field of a node.
I've tried to use &node[title]=testnode&node[type]=story&node[field_test][0][it][value]=testtting as suggested in the Services Handbook. The node is updated (I get the system message for successfully updating), all fields are updated, except the selectlist.
Anyone facing the same problem has found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe how you are updating the node i.e node_save() , The $node object that needs to be passed might not have the correct structure for the select list,

```
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = 'something';
```

You can always try to node_load($nid) and watchdog it to see the structure of your select field, and then verify if you are creating the $node object correctly before doing node_save().

This is just my guess, I can provide more correct answer once I can see the relevant code.

Cheers